# Efficient computation of 2^x (antilog2) for fixed-point

Tags: algorithms, math, fixed-point

I've created a log2 AGC for an FPGA project, similar to [Dan Boschen's solution in this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89364/implementing-logarithmic-agc-automatic-gain-control). I implemented a hardware version of log2 based on Dan's linked page in the previous question - [efficient floating point log2 computation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/88520/efficient-log2-and-db-from-floating-point-and-fixed-point-representation).

For the antilog2 operation, I used simple bit shifting for the integer component, but resorted to using Horner's rule and the set of coefficients from [robert bristow-johnson](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20444/books-resources-for-implementing-various-mathematical-functions-in-fixed-point-a/20482#20482). This works very well, but I require several multipliers for the fractional part of the exponent.

Is there an algorithm to approximate antilog2 of the fractional component of fixed-point numbers efficiently, in a similar manner to the Dan's efficient log2?

I realise I can use a simple lookup table to achieve a multiplier-free version, but I'm interested if there is already something out there using simple bit shifting and recasting tricks.

Comment: Interesting question!  Not sure if it helps, but [this repo](https://github.com/Photosounder/rouziclib/blob/master/rouziclib/approximations/fixed_point.c) has some table-based approaches that might mean not re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this repo Peter. This will definitely help if I have to resort to tables.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to put it to use!

Comment: How approximate can it be, and how do you define "efficient"?  Without knowing that there's no way of knowing what you might find best or sufficient.

Comment: Fair point @TimWescott. By efficiency, I mean that I'd like to trim FPGA resources in both DSP slices and LUTs. In terms of the estimation accuracy, I'd be happy with 1-2 dB. Granted I don't have an exact quantitative measure at the moment, but I'm just playing around with a few concepts to try target optimal resource usage on my FPGA.